# Java Binary to Decimal Format/ How to assign a proper input?

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I'm writing a java program to convert binary numbers into decimal numbers, I've managed to get my program to work in that regard.

My question is how do I make it so the user has to enter a binary number or else an error will pop up and the question will end? 
Also, How do I repeat my statement so the user can calculate multiple binary number conversions?

If you give an answer could you explain how each step works and show how the code should looks?

My current program is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

    int binarynum =input.nextInt();
    int binary=binarynum;
    int decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;

    while(true){

        if(binary == 0){
            break;

        } else {

            int temp = binary%10;
            decimal += temp*Math.pow(2, power);
            binary = binary/10;
            power++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Binary = "+binarynum+" Decimal = "+decimal); ;
}
```

Comment: `String input; while (!(input = input.nextLine()).matches("[01]+")) System.out.println("Invalid binary number. Please try again: "); int binarynum = Integer.parseInt(input);`

Comment: Note that your method works on a very limited set of values. It'll fail on `10000000000` because it's out of `int` range.

Comment: You should get the input as a String, and produce the decimal as a String too. At present you're just recalculating binary as binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version keeps on asking the user to give a binary value.

If it's not binary, an exception will be thrown.

Finally, to stop the process, you just have to enter `END` as input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a binary number (END to exit): ");
        try {
            String inputValue = input.next();
            if (inputValue.equals("END")) {
                break;
            }
            if (!inputValue.matches("[01]+")) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid binary input");
            }

            int binarynum = Integer.valueOf(inputValue);
            int decimal = getDecimalValue(binarynum);
            System.out.println("Binary = " + binarynum + " Decimal = " + decimal);
            System.out.println();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static int getDecimalValue(int binary) {
    int decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (binary == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            int temp = binary % 10;
            decimal += temp * Math.pow(2, power);
            binary = binary / 10;
            power++;
        }
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: This program worked, but it was initially missing a return statement for the value of decimal. After the while statement, it should be: ...                                                                                                                                                     }return decimal;

Comment: I don't know if you missed the last line of code but the return decimal do exist. Anyway I'm glad that my suggestion worked, can you please mark it as the answer of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner.hasNextInt(int radix)` and `Scanner.nextInt(int radix)` with a radix of 2. Of course `nextInt(2)` would do all your work, so:

```
System.out.println("Enter a binary number:");
while (!input.hasNextInt(2)) {
    System.out.println("Only 0 and 1 allowed. Enter a binary number:");
    input.nextLine(); // Skip the input line.
}
int binarynum = input.nextInt(); // input.nextInt(2) would give the result.
```

Scanner has for its `next...()` methods corresponding test methods `hasNext...()`.